# NextJS AUTH + Web Service Worker - catch or query the original JWT token

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, service-worker, next-auth

We have a nextJs + Next-Auth application, which uses OAuth external authentication. This site sets a JWT token which can be captured in the `jwt()` callback, and can be include into the session token, and send back to the nextJs app. This JWT token is needed on client side also, because must be attached to external REST API calls as authorization token.

My plan is to set a Service Worker on the client side to catch and store the JWT token, extract it from the nextJs session, and later by listening to fetch events modify the call and adds to the http header as authorization bearer token.

There are several problem arises:

- first: the worker must be installed before the external API call happens. I must add the worker install to the pages with `useEffect()`. But using a SSO the application might begins on any page. I don't think it is a good solution to add this `useEffect()` and `worker install` to all pages we have.
- lets suppose the worker is installed, how to read the nextJs session token? How to capture a session token? Currently I read the JWT token from the session using `useSession()` on the page and sends it to the worker using `postMessage()` - but also: I dont want to put this code to all my pages, and still don't know which pages loads first.
- third: when the JWT token is read and stored by the ˙worker, there is no need to send the jwt token every time when a nextJs session is read (its a quite long string). How can I *inform* the next-auth side, that the token is extracted, and no longer is needed to attach to the session token?

Almost all the problem could be solved, if I would able to send a custom query to the next-auth side, other than the existing callbacks, to query the JWT token when the ˙service worker` is  installed and up. It would store the JWT token inside the worker, then modify the fetch calls as described above. *Is it possible to extend the Next-Auth rest api with additional methods?*

```
// on all page.tsx ?
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => await workerInstall());
}, []);

// this is a library .js code
async function workerInstall() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  }
}
```

Also: how to install the `service worker` on (all of) the NextJS application pages?